# Encryption tool that supports multiple separate decryptions?

Tags: encryption

Is there a tool that will allow me to encrypt n plaintexts with n corresponding keys such that:

- the cipher text is one file with no clue as to the value of n.
- decrypting with key i (1<=i<=n) produces plaintext i.
- n > 1

Edit: an example of a scheme that meets the second and third criteria but not the first would be a tar file containing n separate GPG-encrypted files.

Edit 2: an example of a scheme that meets all three criteria would be TrueCrypt hidden volumes, but I am looking for something that works with individual files rather than a disk encryption system (plus this doesn't really meet the first criterion as the value of n is always 2)

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  n keys encrypting n plaintexts would produce n ciphertexts, or at least one ciphertext that's n times as large as the original.

Comment: Yes I imagined it would have to be a ciphertext which is about the same size as the sum of all the plaintexts.

Comment: If you really require that you have n separate ciphertexts, and distribute all of them at once, the size of the file is going to reveal n.  Unless you have a massive amount of padding that keeps the size of the cryptotext a constant (and reduce the padding to keep it constant regardless of n), then I see no way to prevent the size of the cryptotext from revealing n.

Comment: Abstract problems like this are notoriously difficult to solve.  Real world problems have more space to explore in, so I suggest you expand the problem.

Comment: I know this isn't exactly what you're looking for, but would Shamir's Secret Sharing  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing address your needs?

Comment: @john deters: thanks but it's almost the opposite that I want - for any of a number of users to recover the secret, but a different secret.

Comment: @steve sether: I understand, and thank you for trying to help me articulate my question better. This is for a type of game/exercise and is indeed a very artificial situation.

Comment: So create a file F of size S, where S >> n*plaintextSize.  Add random padding to ensure that File S is always size S, regardless of n.  Choose S carefully, so as to never be smaller than n*plaintextSize.  Essentially you're trying to hide the meta-data here, and to do that, you need to make it so there's never any information in the file size.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that all ciphertexts are of the same length (some tricky padding could help with different lengths), you can just XOR the plaintexts together:

```
C = M1 xor M2 xor M3
K1 = M2 xor M3
K2 = M1 xor M3
K3 = M1 xor M2
M1' = C xor K1
M2' = C xor K2
M3' = C xor K3
... and so forth for Mn and Kn
```

**Important:** even if the plaintext is unpredictable, this "encryption" scheme is very weak; do not use it for confidential data.

Comment: Clever, but not really an answer.

Comment: Because i am not giving a tool?

Comment: The OP is asking for a real solution, you are offering a toy.